# root profile error

Tags: root, tty, user-profile

I had a problem with my root account on Ubuntu 14.04. when I login by using root account, I received this error:

```
Error found when loading /root/.profile: stdin: is not a tty
As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

Comment: Why login with the root account? `sudo` or `gksudo` etc can do all you need from a regular account

Comment: have you edited any bash file in root folder?

Comment: please refer to here `http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/faq.html` and try all three approches to solve the same proglem

Answer (score 5):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xen-3.1/+bug/1167281

`stdin: is not a tty` due to `mesg n` instead of `tty -s && mesg n` in `.profile`

Try the said method to add `tty -s &&` in front of the line `mesg n` and see if it helps. The difference is, in case your problem is also caused by the `mesg n` in yout profile.